# Error when creating CSR with the attributes: "T" and "uidNumber" in the subject

Tags: openssl, x509

For an integration we are going to do at work we need to provide to a local government organization a Certificate Signing Request file. This local company needs to have the following attributes in the subject when generating the CSR file:

```
CN=data/O=data/OU=data/T=data/C=AU/dnQualifier=data/uidNumber=data/uid=data/serialNumber=data/emailAddress=john@example.com
```

When I generate the CSR file with OpenSSL using the following command:

```
$ openssl req -new -key example.pem -out example.csr -subj "{the above subject}"
```

I get the next errors:

```
req: Skipping unknown attribute "T"                                     
req: Skipping unknown attribute "uidNumber"
```

I tried on Debian 9.5 and Ubuntu 18.04 with the same result.

After investigating I added new OIDs in the `/etc/ssl/openssl.cfg` file:

```
[ new_oids ]
uidNumber = 1.2.3.4
T = 1.2.3.4.2
```

And finally it generated without problems.

I was able to see `T` and `uidNumber` attributes in the subject when verifying the CSR file with:

```
$ openssl req -in example.csr -noout -text
```

Although I got the attributes in the subject by updating OpenSSL configuration file, I am really not sure of the meaning of `1.2.3.4` and `1.2.3.4.2` values I used when defining them (I just followed the pattern of the commented example in the file). Does those values affect the CSR file I am going to use although the attributes are present as expected?

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am really not sure of the meaning of `1.2.3.4` and `1.2.3.4.2` values I
>   used when defining them

Normally, those OIDs have a meaning that is understood by all parties involved. Typically their values and meanings are published in some known place. A handy site to look them up is [this OID repository](http://www.oid-info.com). The OIDs that you have chosen do not have a known meaning.

> Does those values affect the CSR file I am going to use although the
>   attributes are present as expected?

Yes, the OIDs will be part of the PEM- or DER-encoded CSR and are used by the receiver to parse the file. In fact, *only* the OIDs are included and not the names of the attributes themselves. With your choice of OIDs, the receiver will not able to understand what the meaning of the associated values is. So you should make sure to choose OID values that match with the intended meaning of the attributes.

The `T` attribute probably refers to [`title` with OID `2.5.4.12`](http://www.oid-info.com/get/2.5.4.12), for which the short name `T` can be used. That short name does not seem to be standardized, but see the [ITU X.520 spec](https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-X.520-201610-I!!PDF-E&type=items) section `6.4.3 title`, which mentions `T = "Manager, Distributed Applications"` as an example.

The `uidNumber` attribute probably refers to [OID `1.3.6.1.1.1.1.0`](http://www.oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.1.1.1.0).

However, in stead of second guessing the intentions of the person who wrote the specification that you are using, it would be better to request that the OIDs are added to it, preferably for all attributes. That way, all parties know exactly what the expected attribute OIDs are and how to interpret the associated values.

Comment: Thank you very much Reinier, I was totally unaware of the meaning of those values. It is really good information.